# How to insert values to url using csv in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

In my test when I select number of children as 1

```
from csv, by using ${age} as reference
```

I should get the url as:

> &when=29-05-2016&until=&flexibility=true&flexibleDays=3&noOfAdults=2&noOfSeniors‌​=0&noOfChildren=2&childrenAge=2&duration=7114&

and when I select number of children as 2 I should get the URL as:

> &when=29-05-2016&until=&flexibility=true&flexibleDays=3&noOfAdults=2&noOfSeniors‌​=0&noOfChildren=2&childrenAge=2%2C4&duration=7114&

How can i do this? I tried giving comma separated data in csv, but it's not taking second value in CSV which is there after comma.

Comment: Can you provide relevant part of your JMX? Based in your description you need a second line of data in your CSV not more values after comma.

Comment: Hai now its taking comma separated multiple values for age.In the "view result tree " response data ,request i'm getting as 'childrenAge=2,2,4'.and it works fine. meanwhile i used beanshell sampler also to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai now its taking comma separated multiple values for age.In the "**view result tree** " **response data** ,**request** i'm getting as 'childrenAge=2,2,4'.and it works fine.
meanwhile i used **beanshell** sampler also to achieve the same.